# Interactive poput at google spreadsheet, HOW: GUI or HTML service?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a doubt regarding how can I interact with the user at a google spreadsheet.
The idea is to show a menu, with some options, let the user select one and then process some spreadsheet data according to it. This should be done within the srpeadsheet.

The problem is, I'm not sure what is the best way to accomplish this.
At a firs instance, I though at HTML service, but I'm not sure the communication to the server side works from a spreadsheet.

I have this code, which in fact, acess to the server side, but It's pretty simple

```
function showHtml(htmlText){
 htmlText=htmlText+'<input type="button" value="Close"  onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlText);
  thisSpr.show(html);
}
```

Any ideas? Just want to know which should be the best way and one or two tips on how to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Class Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu), maybe you can get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is just to make a new menu entry. I need something different. There are some templates avaiable at a certain spreadsheet. When the user selects send mail, all the avaiable templates should be prompted to the user. Then he can choose one, and after that the script should send one email according to the selected template. That's why I need some kind of interactive popup.